# Mapping pandas dataframe column to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series, categorical-data

I have a case of a dataframe containing a categorical variable of high cardinality (many unique values). I would like to re-code that variable to a set of values (the top most frequent values) and replace all other values with a catch-all category ("others"). To give a simple example:

Here are the two values which should stay unchanged:

```
top_values = ['apple', 'orange']
```

I established them based on their frequency in the following dataframe column:

```
{'fruits': {0: 'apple',
1: 'apple',
2: 'orange',
3: 'orange',
4: 'banana',
5: 'grape'}}
```

That dataframe column should be re-coded as follows:

```
{'fruits': {0: 'apple',
1: 'apple',
2: 'orange',
3: 'orange',
4: 'other',
5: 'other'}}
```

How to do that? (The dataframe has millions of records)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least a couple of methods you can use:

#### [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) + Boolean indexing

```
df['fruits'].where(df['fruits'].isin(top_values), 'other', inplace=True)
```

#### [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + Boolean indexing

```
df.loc[~df['fruits'].isin(top_values), 'fruits'] = 'other'
```

*After* this process, you will probably want to turn your series into a categorical:

```
df['fruits'] = df['fruits'].astype('category')
```

Doing this *before* the value replacement operation probably won't help as your input series has high cardinality.

Comment: It occurs to me that the WHERE code snippet lacks reversion - it would replace the values that match pattern, rather than those which don't.

Comment: @Nick, Yep it's deceptive (vs e.g. `np.where`). Use `pd.Series.mask` to change values matching a condition; use `pd.Series.where` to change values *not* matching a condition. The lack of intuition is probably why it has never caught on.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.newCol = df.apply(lambda row: row.fruits if row.fruits in top_values else 'others' )
```